# Find latitude/longitude ranges for cities

Tags: geolocation, gis, latitude-longitude, geocode

Is there a way to find the range of latitude and longitude included within a set of certain cities?
Ex. I am trying to find all ranges of lat/longs which are included within the city boundaries of Atlanta.

Comment: With what you are working? QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment because I don't yet have a sufficient reputation.  However, this question is hard to answer because depending on the level of accuracy of the XY coords, you are going to produce a huge range of values.  For example, [wmf labs](https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Atlanta&params=33_45_18_N_84_23_24_W_type:city_region:US-GA) goes to the 2nd level of XY coord precision (33.755, -84.39), which would produce much less XY coordinate pairs within a given polygon than using the [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Rounding_and_decimal_places) to the 6th level (e.g. 33.756732, -84.425291).

Once you've established that, then I assume your workflow would be to import the polygon of Atlanta > set your coordinate system > use the bounding coordinates that form Atlanta as your area of interest > set the level of precision > using the level of precision, produce a table(?)/list(?)/whatever format you want(need to establish this) of points that INTERSECT the polygon...R has packages to do this, SQL Spatial, JavaScript APIs, etc.